# Defining a function for arguments with multiple possible Types

Tags: julia

What is the best way to define a function with an argument that can have multiple types?
e.g. `Float64` or `Array{Float64}` / `Array{Float64,2}` or `SparseMatrixCSC{Float64}`

Let's say I define the following function:

```
function meanValue(a::Array{Float64})
  return mean(a)
end
```

How can I define functions for the cases of a scalar value or a sparse vector without copy-pasting the content of the original function?
Thank you!

Comment: Julia automatically specializes on the given types, so `meanValue(a)` with no type parameters will not have a performance penalty. They are perfectly fine to use, but note this is for safety and not for speed. In many cases, not adding parameters, called duck-typing, is preferred. See [this blog post](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/type-dispatch-design-post-object-oriented-programming-julia/).

Comment: That clarifies a lot. I assumed specifying the type will increase speed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Union` in such cases, e.g.

```
julia> f(x::Union{Float64, Int}) = typeof(x)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(1)
Int64

julia> f(1.0)
Float64

julia> f(true)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Bool)
Closest candidates are:
  f(::Union{Float64, Int64}) at REPL[1]:1
```

A good example of such an approach is `Base.Chars`:

```
julia> Base.Chars
Union{AbstractArray{Char,1}, Char, Set{Char}, Tuple{Vararg{Char,N} where N}}
```

It is used e.g. in `strip` function.

However, in many cases it will be fine not to specify accepted types, e.g.:

```
f(x) = typeof(x)
```

this has no performance penalty and has a benefit that if in the future you want to use the function on a type you did not think of initially you do not have to redefine it (it is even possible that the type was not defined when function was defined).

Of course there are situations when you want to specify accepted types - then you can:

1. use `Union`;
2. handle cases separately and/or use an abstract type that is a supertype of desired types (see @DNF's answer).

Comment: Maybe worth explicitly mentioning `Union{AbstractArray{Float64}, Float64}`, i.e. union which covers the types mentioned by OP.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of listing a lot of types in your function signature, you can try to be general. Do you want means for all sorts of arrays, and all kinds of numbers? Then, perhaps try

```
function meanvalue(a::AbstractArray{<:Number})
    return mean(a)
end
```

And then you want to capture those cases with scalar inputs:

```
meanvalue(x::Number) = x
```

Now, you've covered most possibilities, at least concerning arrays.